# PHP processes load and stuck taking all CPUs

Tags: php, centos, overloading, cpanel

I have a PHP script that enables me to have a Social Network and such similiar.

Normally, there isn't any problem, my server is a VPS with:

- 2.4 GHz CPU
- 4 Cores
- 8 GB of RAM
- 150GB SSD
- CentOS 7.1 with cPanel.

The problem is that normally server can mantain at a CPU load of 30-40% around 30 concurrent users. But sometimes, I don't know for what reason, the load goes really high, to 98-100% all the time. Even if users log out and there is even just 3-4 persons in the website, the server load remains to 98-100% all the time 'til I don't restart the server.

So, I noticed, using **top** command via SSH, that gets created a process in PHP with the user as the owner of the webspace (created via cPanel) and as command, PHP. The load for this process is from 20% to 27%.

The fact is that more of these PHP processes get created more time that pass.
For example, after 30 minutes, there is another PHP process with the same characteristics of the first process. And both, together, take 50-60% of the CPU load. More time pass, more process get created, to a max of 4 processes like this. (Is because my CPU has 4 cores?).

If I kill these processes via **kill [pid]** in 1-2 minutes, server goes back to 3% even with 10-15 concurrent users.

What is the problem? It is strictly php-file related or what? I even tried doing events on the website to check WHAT actions these PHP processes (even useless) that start. Because if I kill them, website continues to work very good!

What could be the problem?

There is a screen of CPU usage:
[image: Screenshot]

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a process is making a lot of I/O operations like database calls etc, it can considerably increase the CPU load. In your case you are sure of the process which is the cause behind this high load. Noticing that load increases overt time,you should carefully look at the PHP script for memory leaks, lots of sessions, lots of nested loops with IO tugged in between and try to isolate the reason for it. good luck

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.
The problem is that these processes come random. They arrive and start to take so much CPU, but they are useless. In fact, if I kill them, my website still works even more good. They don't need to anything... that's the problem.

This isn't like I/O operations, I think. Because if they don't do really anything, what could be the reason?

Comment: I am not convined that if a process does not have visible effect on the website, it is useless or not doing anything. Imagine a useless function which does nothing but load up data from a really massive db table. In this case although you won`t see any visible changes but it still will consume a lot of memory. So you need to still look out for these.

Comment: Thank you, @thepiyush.
Exists a way to know from which file the process started? The only thing I can understand is that comes from index.php, which doesn't help so much, because it calls all other php files...

Comment: in index,php you can try debug_print_backtrace() which prints a PHP backtrace. It prints the function calls, included/required files and eval()ed stuff.Otherwise look up PHP debugging, it will reveal a wealth of information.